# Are conspiracy theory based questions allowed here?

Tags: discussion, support

There are lots of conspiracy theories out there. These conspiracy theories are backed by lots of thought-provoking theories which can make anyone skeptical. For example, "Earth is Flat" is backed by proper gravitational theories (like Earth is accelerating in one direction and Einstein's Principle of Equivalence is applicable). Also, they say that all the NASA pictures are fake. Rich and powerful people are actually misleading us.

Are such questions allowed here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

There are plenty of examples of such questions here.